# Swift crash "EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000... "

Tags: swift, crashlytics

I do have three different crashes in my iOS app; different code locations, but all three with "exc_breakpoint 0x000000...". I cannot reproduce them, they happen on different devices and different iOS versions.

As mentioned, I cannot reproduce them, none of our testers had a crash like that, but according to crashlytics they happen too often to ignore.

**Above all I'm generally interested in what this `EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000...` means, e.g. unwrapping nil-optional, cast error, ...**

first one:

[image]

second one:
[image]

third one:
[image]

Comment: You'll need to add more details, like what's happening on line 202 of ...ViewController.swift. Also the third crash doesn't seem to be anything to do with the first two.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: I am having the same issue, but can't find the solution. Also, can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you guys found a solution, yet? I have the same issue for more than 6 months now.... not a lot users are affected, but anyhow, I'd like to fix this. @JiangWang

Comment: I am still facing this issue... can't reproduce it! Any solutions for this??

Answer (score 17):

I am also struggling with the similar Crash Log ie. EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000010006a4d4. As stated, non of our QA were also able to replicate it but happened only few times. In my case, I found a pattern on all the crashes where it occurred. It occurred on iPhone 6S and iPhone 6 devices and both have only 2% to 4% RAM Free when crash occurred.

I believe it is due to low memory issue. Crash only happened after few instructions on app delegate pointing to random instructions. Crashlytics already stated that the issue lies within Xcode. You can read answer from [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/general-error-with-crashlytics-and-swift-2-0-exc-breakpoint/59242) for that.

Somewhere I read that EXC_BREAKPOINT occurs when swift has no idea of what happened with the Memory i.e. I guess in my case memory issue due to lower memory.

I have upgraded my Xcode to 7.3 along with swift and I am testing with new builds to replicate the crash. Let's see what will happen. I will post the result after testing and see if crash will be replicated or not.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I have same observations. It looks like Swift problem.

Comment: Could you repeat the app crash?

Comment: any updates on this. running into a similar issue. same pattern, but happens on the same lines of code. is this still happening. currently on xcode 9, swift 3.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue too and it's affecting a good number of users.  Crashlytics reports them having over 130 MB of RAM free.  Also, it reports the issue occurring on lines of code that don't even exist.  (e.g. AppDelegate.swift(476) even though this file only has just over 100 lines.)

Comment: did you guys found a solution, yet? I have the same issue for more than 6 months now.... not a lot users are affected, but anyhow, I'd like to fix this - @horseshoe7

Comment: How much memory is your app using? I see the same problem where I see this crash on devices with <= 3% of RAM. My app uses around 50MB of memory on the screen where this crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my app, but my problem had nothing to do with the device memory, as it might be the case with this error.
the problem was that I was using a `ForEach` to render some items, and I was changing the list size.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, inside the `heightForRowAt` method for a tableView, I was dividing the `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bounds.width / 2`, and the force-unwrapping of the `keyWindow` was the problem. It was nil at that time.

This was possible to debug using XCode's `Organizer -> Crashes -> Select the crash that you need -> Open in project...`
It lead me to the exact line of code which crashed and showed the problem.

Comment: Your comment about the Organizer helped me find more info related to the crash than that provided by Crashlitics. It included a more detailed thread and the exact exception (e.g. index out of range, unexpectedly found nil, etc) Thank you!

Answer (score -6):

Check your background fetch intervel in appDelegate file.

Ex:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {      

    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

    return true
}
```

remove `application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)`
line from didFinishMethod and check again or comment it.

Comment: I do not have ```setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval``` in my app; I do not know what this could have to do with my crashes :)

Comment: can you show viewContoller.swift line no. 202 error

Comment: on that line, it's just a ```return false``` from the method... I really don't get it :(

Comment: please share your code so it more easy to find exact problem.