# Unexplainable Swift EXC_BREAKPOINT Crash

Tags: ios, swift

consider the following code:

```
@objc public func endAllSessionsWithReason(_ reason: Reason, completion completionBlock: (() -> Void)?) {
    let allActiveSessions = self.activeSessions.map({$0.value})

    for session in allActiveSessions {
        if (reason != .undetermined) {
            session.reason = reason
        }

        self.endSession(session, deleteSession: false)
    }

    let allActiveSessionIds = allActiveSessions.map({$0.sessionId})
    self.deleteSessionsWithIds(sessionIds: allActiveSessionIds, completion: completionBlock)
}
```

Crashlytics is reporting the following crash in this code:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000103032788
SessionController.swift line 183
specialized SessionController.endAllSessionsWithReason(_:completion:)
```

where line 183 refers to:

```
let allActiveSessionIds = allActiveSessions.map({$0.sessionId})
```

I've tried figuring out what could cause this crash for a few days now, and haven't been able to reproduce it.  I don't see any implicit unwraps or optionals here, but `sessionId` is a non-optional value in the session object if that matters.

`self.activeSessions` is a non-optional value as well, but can be empty.

I am using swift 4.1, and the crashes occur on on iOS devices running all the different flavors of iOS 10, 11, and 12.  The app does support some builds of iOS 9, but none have been reported (although that may be irrelevant because the iOS 9 user base for the app is *extremely* small).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36469080/341994

Comment: Is it possible that `allActiveSessions` was mutated by another thread?

Comment: @Paulw11 it's possible, yes.  I'd have to review this code a bit more to be sure.  I am on a vacation now, will check when I return.  Cheers.

Comment: @Paulw11 admittedly I've been back from vacation for some time - apologies for not responding sooner :).  I gave your message some thought and I believe threading to be the root cause (surprise surprise), as you pointed out.  A coworker just reviewed this same issue and has come to the same conclusion, so it's nice to have two points of reference.  I appreciate the feedback - when I confirm a fix I'll post an update.

Comment: I've had a potential fix under review by my team for a few days now (other things got in the way) but we seem to be in agreement that it was a threading issue, much like you pointed out.  If you want to post an answer I'll gladly accept it @Paulw11! Thanks for leading me to the right direction!